# How can I search through a string a get only an specific part of it JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to search only a specific piece of a string and show it using nothing more than JS or Jquery.

For example, (**It just looks like a JSON, but it's not, it's just brackets some stuff ;)** ):

```
var data = 
 [{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":
   [
     {"name":"child2","id":3},
     {"name":"child1","id":2}
   ]
 }];
```

I'd like to pick up only the ID numbers:

The "code" below is not a language, it's just an example to help understanding what I'd like to do on JS/jQuery

> var IDs = [searchThrough] data [where there is] "id": [getContent] after : and before , or } alert("IDs: "+IDs);

It allows me to:

1 - set a parameter of what I want from a string `find "id":` on `data`.

2 - set the start and end for getting the content `after : and before , or }`

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

"Beam me up Scotty!"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for pointing out :D, so how can I do it?

Comment: So, to clarify, you're trying to get all the `id` properties in the array of objects? Even those on the `children`?

Comment: kind of, I edited my question to make it clearer, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no regex guru,but this is my try.

```
var data = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":[{"name":"child2","id":3},{"name":"child1","id":2}]}]';
var arrays=[];
var t1=data.match(/"id":[0-9]+(,|})*/g);
for(var x=0;x<t1.length;x++)
{
  arrays.push(t1[x].match(/\d+/));   

}
alert(arrays);
```

Comment: I tried yours and it ran smoother, I think I'll be forced to mark yours as the answer

Comment: @Calne Appreciate It  :) Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to search a String that represents the data. In this case, you could use a regular expression like the following:

```
var matcher = /"id":([^,\}]*/g, // capture all characters between "id" and , or }
    match, IDs = [];

while (match = matcher.exec(data)) {
  IDs.push(match[1]);
}

alert(IDs);
```

Comment: Fantastic, that was exactly what I was looking for thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

If we take the assumption that you are dealing with a string, we can pull out the data using regular expression:

```js
var str = '[{"name":"node1","id":1,"is_open":true,"children":\n   [\n     {"name":"child2","id":3},\n     {"name":"child1","id":2}\n   ]\n }];';
var regex = /"id":([0-9]*)/g;
var match = regex.exec(str);

var res = new Array();

while (match != null) {
  res.push(match[1]);
  match = regex.exec(str);
}

var ids = res.join();

alert("IDs: " + ids);
```

This demo will give you an alert box with the content "IDs: 1,3,2"